# How To Concate <input> tage value='' Attribute in php

Tags: php, mysql, input, concatenation

How To Concate `<input> tage value=''` Attribute in php?

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{ 

    <input name='eid' disabled='disabled' value='".<?php echo $_GET['eid']; ?>."'>
    echo "<tr><td>
    <input name='eid' disabled='disabled' value='".<?php echo $_GET['eid']; ?>."'>
    </td><td>".$r['bname']."</td><td>".$r['aname']."</td><td>".$r['price']."</td><td>".$r['avalable_book']."</td><td><a class='btn btn-framed btn-color-primary btn-small' href='Bookdetail.php?eid=".$r['bid']."'>Edit</a>&nbsp;<a class='btn btn-framed btn-color-primary btn-small' href='BookDetail.php'>Cancel</a></td></tr>";

}
```

Comment: Your code has errors with missing '<?php' and '?>' tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `<?php ?>` tags within your PHP tags. Also, you have to echo everything that is HTML.

Take a look at this:

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{ 

    echo "<input name='eid' disabled='disabled' value='". $_GET['eid']."'>";
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<input name='eid' disabled='disabled' value='". $_GET['eid']."'>";
    echo "</td><td>".$r['bname']."</td><td>".$r['aname']."</td><td>".$r['price']."</td><td>".$r['avalable_book']."</td><td><a class='btn btn-framed btn-color-primary btn-small' href='Bookdetail.php?eid=".$r['bid']."'>Edit</a>&nbsp;<a class='btn btn-framed btn-color-primary btn-small' href='BookDetail.php'>Cancel</a></td></tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    echo "<input name='eid' disabled='disabled' value='" . $_GET['eid'] . "'> " . $r['bname'] . " " . $r['aname'] . " " . $r['price'] . " " . $r['avalable_book'] . " Edit Cancel";
    }
```

I`m not really sure what output you want to get, but you concatenate with ' . ' (dot) in PHP, as in above example.

Answer (score 0):

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            echo "Edit Cancel";
        }